# MongoDB Query double nested documents in array

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering how I can query from an embedded document inside an array. I have following structure:

```
{ "targetId" : 2, "metaData" : [ {     "key" : "id",     "value" : 1 },     {     "key" :        "name",     "value" : "Parisa" },     {     "key" : "img",     "value" : {     "imgid" : 1,         "imgName" : "img1" } } ]
```

I could search simple key-values like key = id and value =1, but I could not search based on the values with embedded document e.g. key="img"

I tried following query but it does not work:

```
db.test.find({"metaData":{$elemMatch:{"key":"img", "value":{"imgid":1}}}})
```

Could you please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "value" part of your query is a little off.  You need to put the document element in the criteria:

```
b.test.find({"metaData":{$elemMatch:{"key":"img", "value.imgid":1}}})
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not return any document!