# Query a double nested array with multiple filters

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

This is my data:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "items": [
        [{"name": "a"}, {"size": 2}, {"color": "red"}],
        [{"name": "b"}, {"size": 4}, {"color": "blue"}],
        [{"name": "c"}, {"size": 6}, {"color": "pink"}]
    ]    
},
{
    "_id": 2,
    "items": [
        [{"name": "a"}, {"size": 3}, {"color": "black"}],
        [{"name": "e"}, {"size": 6}, {"color": "blue"}],
        [{"name": "g"}, {"size": 9}, {"color": "pink"}]
    ]    
}
```

And I need to do something like this:

`db.foo.find({items.name: "a", items.color: "red"})`

It's not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Query double nested documents in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25393148/mongodb-query-double-nested-documents-in-array)

Comment: my collection is different.

Comment: try something like `db.foo.find({ items: {$all: ["name": "a"],  ["color": "red"]}});` Let me know if that works

Comment: It didn't work. I got an error -> Unexpected token :

Answer (score 0):

For this, you could make use of the `$elemMatch` keyword.

```
db.foo.find({items: {$elemMatch: {name: "a", color: "red"} } });
```

That should allow to match on multiple fields of a document within an array.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
db.foo.find({ 
    items: {
        $elemMatch: {
            $all: [
                {$elemMatch: {"name": "a"}},
                {$elemMatch: {"color": "red"}}
               ]
         }
    }
});
```

Thanks guys!!